# Is there a LaTeX class specifically for generating License Agreements?

Tags: document-classes, ctan, licensing

Is there a LaTeX class designed, or adaptable, to generate License Agreements easily?

For example, it should be easy to generate sections: Terms, Conditions, etc., with numbered/unnumbered subsections/paragraphs.  In addition, for license agreements that need to be signed and delivered, it should have sections for licensee and licensor (similar to author sections?) with the option of having underlining areas where someone would fill in their info and signature by hand.

Comment: CTAN does have a [Legal topic](http://www.ctan.org/topic/legal), but nothing recent for the English language.  Any other ideas of where to look?

Comment: AND IT MUST MAKE ALL TEXT UNREADABLE BY MAKING IT UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not appear to be any such class, perhaps because nobody has thought it general enough to create one.  You're right that it's the kind of thing that might make sense to be put into a class or package, but unless someone thinks it's a worthwhile idea to do so (perhaps based on your question) I think you're out of luck.